# Redis set ttl on key idempotently

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I'm trying to use pipelines to process hundreds of thousands of keys being constantly added to a redis database.

Is there an idempotent method in Redis of setting the ttl if it does not exist on a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lua script would be the most potent approach - see [`EVAL`'s documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval) for more details on how to compose such scripts, and refer to [`SCRIPT LOAD`](https://redis.io/commands/script-load) and [`EVALSHA`](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha) for running them.

Something like the following example should fix you up:

```
if tonumber(redis.call('TTL', KEYS[1])) < 1 then
  redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
end
```